# How to do the right resize of image?

Tags: java, image

I have a problem with getting the right size of the image.

For this, I have this method the do the resize of the image and somehow the logic needs a small change to get the right size of the image :

```
private final Integer width = 170;
private final Integer height = 140;
private final Integer maxFeatImageHeight = 600;
private final Integer maxFeatImageWidth = 600;
   /**
 * @param featureImage .
 * @return byte[]
 * @throws Exception
 */
private byte[] resizeFeatureImage(MultipartFile featureImage) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(featureImage.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        double featImageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
        double featImageHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

        if (featImageHeight > maxFeatImageHeight || featImageWidth > maxFeatImageWidth)
        {
         // Sanity check on the input (division by zero, infinity):
            if (featImageWidth <= 1 || featImageHeight <= 1) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error ..." + featureImage);
            }

            // The scaling factors to reach to maxima on width and height:
            double xScale = maxFeatImageWidth   / featImageWidth;
            double yScale = maxFeatImageHeight  / featImageHeight;

            // Proportional (scale width and height by the same factor):
            double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

            // (Possibly) Do not enlarge:
            scale = Math.min(1.0, scale);

            int finalWidth = Math.min((int) Math.round(scale * featImageWidth), maxFeatImageWidth);
            int finalHeight = Math.min((int) Math.round(scale * featImageHeight), maxFeatImageHeight);
            double ratio = featImageWidth / featImageHeight;
            // width is bigger then height
            if (ratio > 1)
            {
                finalWidth = maxFeatImageWidth;
                finalHeight = (int) Math.round(maxFeatImageHeight / ratio);
            }
            // height is bigger then width
            else if (ratio < 1)
            {
                finalWidth = (int) Math.round(maxFeatImageWidth / ratio);
                finalHeight = maxFeatImageHeight;
            }
            // width and height are equal
            else
            {
                finalHeight = maxFeatImageHeight;
                finalWidth = maxFeatImageWidth;
            }

            logger.info("[resizeFeatureImage] [FEATURE IMAGE RESIZE] Starting to resize feature Image");
            Graphics2D g2d;
            BufferedImage resizedImage;

            if (featureImage.getContentType().contains("png"))
            {
                resizedImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            }
            else
            {
                resizedImage = new BufferedImage(finalWidth, finalHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            }

            g2d = resizedImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.drawImage(ImageIO.read(featureImage.getInputStream()), 0, 0, finalWidth, finalHeight,
                    null);
            g2d.dispose();

            ImageIO.write(resizedImage, featureImage.getContentType().split("/")[1], baos);
            logger.info("[resizeFeatureImage] [FEATURE IMAGE RESIZE] Feature image resized!");
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        else
        {
            ImageIO.write(originalImage, featureImage.getContentType().split("/")[1], baos);
            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.warn("[resizeFeatureImage] [STATUS] - ERROR ");
        logger.warn("[resizeFeatureImage] [EXCEPTION] " + e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new IOException("The file you uploaded can be damaged or has incorrect encoding.");
    }
}
```

So every image is shown smaller than the space she has
in the image below you can see that there is a lot of white space that isn't being used, and definitely that means I am doing something wrong in my method that is causing that, I have check much many time this method and I don't really know why or is this happening, can anyone one help me edit this method if is need I would really appreciate that .
the images are being shown like this: 
[image]

Comment: are you sure that the images themselfes contains a border and it's not the display program which add's a border or in CSS a margin is added?

Comment: I don't know cause I am not able to read all the code correctly but have you consider when is smaller the max to do it max so can look better

Comment: @SirFartALot yeah is a backend problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static final int MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH = 600;
private static final int MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH = 600;

double featImageWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
double featImageHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

// Sanity check on the input (division by zero, infinity):
if (featImageWidth <= 1 || featImageHeight <= 1) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("..." + featureImage);
}

// The scaling factors to reach to maxima on width and height:
double xScale = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH / featImageWidth;
double yScale = MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT / featImageHeight;

// Proportional (scale width and height by the same factor):
double scale = Math.min(xScale, yScale);

// (Possibly) Do not enlarge:
scale = Math.min(1.0, scale);

int finalWidth = Math.min((int) Math.round(scale * featImageWidth), MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_WIDTH);
int finalHeight = Math.min((int) Math.round(scale * featImageHeigth), MAX_FEAT_IMAGE_HEIGHT);
```

- As you see I turn two things around, to maintain a proportional scaling. Using a ratio (`/`) instead of a scaling factor (`*`) mentally seems to make it harder.
- Determining the scaling for width and for height separately let's one choose the minimal scaling.
- One also may decide, *not* to enlarge small pictures.

Comment: The code with `resizedImage` still is valid. A check for no resizing needed still might be in order.

Comment: ok i will edit my question, more recently the part of code have alook in a min should it look like this cause i am not sure  thank you again

Comment: If you don't mind please have a look I just want to be sure

Answer (score 2):

You only consider the orientation (`ratio` < 1 for vertical, otherwise horizontal or square). That's not enough; you must take into account the target width/height:

```
        int sw = originalImage.getWidth();
        int sh = originalImage.getHeight();
        int swdh = sw * maxFeatImageHeight;
        int shdw = sh * maxFeatImageWidth;
        if (swdh < shdw) {
            finalWidth = swdh / sh;
            finalHeight = maxFeatImageHeight;
        } else {
            finalWidth = maxFeatImageWidth;
            finalHeight = shdw / sw;
        }
```

UPDATE:

OK, let's start with the scales:

```
        double xScale = maxFeatImageWidth/featImageWidth;
        double yScale = maxFeatImageHeight/featImageHeight;
```

You could write:

In the case where yScale < xScale, we need to use yScale:

```
finalWidth = featImageWidth*yScale = featImageWidth*maxFeatImageHeight/featImageHeight;
finalHeight = maxFeatImageHeight;
```

Otherwise, we can use xScale:

```
finalWidth = maxFeatImageWidth;
finalHeight = featImageHeight*xScale = featImageHeight*maxFeatImageWidth/featImageWidth;
```

As all widths and heights are > 0, the result of yScale < xScale is the same as:

```
featImageWidth*featImageHeight*yScale < featImageWidth*featImageHeight*xScale
```

so

```
featImageWidth*featImageHeight*maxFeatImageHeight/featImageHeight < featImageWidth*featImageHeight*maxFeatImageWidth/featImageWidth
```

and

```
maxFeatImageHeight*featImageWidth < maxFeatImageHeight*featImageWidth
```

I have saved these two values as swdh and shdw because they can be reused later.

It avoid conversions from `int` to `double` and from `double` to `int`.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand can you please edit my code and explain a bit more cause I am really unclear, and thank you I appreciate all this

Comment: have a look at the @JoopEggen code I think is better approach

Comment: @IliaTapia it's more complicated, but suite yourself.

Comment: CAn you help me with something

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you should know the size of the image to resize, after that base on that value the if and else statement should function, and calling the resize function you will be able to resize it. I hope that helps. And when you resize make sure that you are able to decrease the pixel as user-defined too.

Comment: I mean how can I go the size, I cannot now that, but what I do know is the max size I want, but I think sth on the method is wrong but thank you I appreciate